# Should I pay the teammate of the research if they don't contribute many things?

Tags: publications

I am an undergraduate student and I join the research project with two other friends (same class) under my professor supervision. I got some money for the project, this money is divided equally to every member and I have a bonus for the leader position.

During the research, my teammate doesn't contribute much work.  When I submit the paper to the conference, they said I should remove their name and give them the money.

In my opinion, I don't want to give them the money because the total budget is not much, just enough for the submission fee.

So what should I do now, this is the first time I submit the paper and I don't want to feel awkward with them because we still have to study together?

**Update:**

After considering all the advice from you guys, I decided to give them their money as the team discussed at the beginning of the project. I think it is fair and they deserve to be paid because they do put their effort into this project.

Comment: _I got some money for the project, this money is divided equally to every member and I have a bonus for the leader position_ seemingly contradicts _the total budget is not much, just enough for the submission fee_

Comment: @user2768 "some money for the project" is the total budget. My team agreed to divide the money equally and I will have some bonus.

Comment: A _submission fee_ may suggest a predatory publisher, do check

Comment: @user2768 I just check again and it is the publication fee, I only need to pay if my paper is accepted.

Comment: 'My team agreed'  Then you've entered into a contract and you need to honour the terms of that contract.  If you haven't submitted the paper yet, then you might do better to choose a venue for publication that doesn't charge any submission or publication fees.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the money for whatever purpose it was assigned: If assigned to pay project team members *equally* plus your *bonus for the leader position*, do that. If assigned for submission fee, pay that. If assigned with no remit, do as you see fit. Personally, I think everyone deserves to be paid for their work, after costs (i.e., the submission fee).